# MacOS Switching between windows of the same application across different workspaces in two monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra

I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve the behavior that is described in the title. Let's say that I have two workspaces on the first monitor and another two on the second. Now, first monitor's workspaces are occupied by Chrome (visible) and Xcode1 and I'm currently working in another Xcode2 window (active) that occupies first workspace of the second monitor. First monitor has Chrome visible, but I need to switch to the other Xcode window.

```
    |-- Monitor1 --|           |-- Monitor2 --|
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
|         |  |         |  |         |  |         |
|         |  |         |  |         |  |         |
| Xcode1  |  | Chrome  |  | Xcode2  |  | Another |
|         |  |         |  |         |  |  app    |
|         |  |         |  |         |  |         |
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
              (visible)    (active)
```

What I would like to do is switch to inactive Xcode1 from active Xcode2. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean Cmd ` doesn't work? Hmm, no it doesn't. Trick is to never put one app on 2 Spaces; it was never designed to work that way.

Comment: Cmd ` works only in scenario when both Xcode2 and Xcode1 are visible. It does not switch workspace on the first monitor (which I would love it to do).

Comment: Yeah, you're fighting the system by having it on more than one Space. No real way round that.

Comment: Unless you're willing to consider two screens as one Space & work that way. That's how I've always done it. I hate the "Displays have separate Spaces" pref

Comment: That's what I thought. Two screens as one Space isn't flexible enough for me, because that way you can't set it up to have Chrome on the left and one window of Xcode on the right.

Comment: Consider asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I have no idea but does "Group Windows by Application" checkbox in Settings > Mission Control  alter the behavior?